# Could not find Assembly System.ComponentModel

Tags: xaml, grid, silverlight-4.0, grouping, system.componentmodel

I'm using Silverlight 4. I need to do grouping in my DataGrid. So I need to add add reference to System.ComponentModel. I could not find System.ComponentModel in "Add Reference". I added reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and the added the following XMLNS in my XAML Page

```
xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=System.ComponentModel"
```

It still says that assembly System.ComponentModel cannot be found. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried to reference the wrong assembly. The `System.ComponentModel` assembly is not available to SL assemblies, even though some of the `System.ComponentModel` *namespaces* are (i.e. a lot of the System.ComponentModel namespaced items in SL actually reside in the *System* assembly).

For more info, check this MSDN page: [.NET Framework Class Library for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194%28v=VS.96%29.aspx). From there you can trace which assembly the item is in.